# How to multiseat (1 computer multiple desktops each one with its monitor and keyborad) on Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: multiseat, multiple-desktops

I would like to use my computer to create to ubuntu desktops that 2 people (or more) can use at the same time.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Possible:  https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/936873/-howto-multiseat-with-ubuntu-16-04-systemd-gdm-proprietary-drivers/

Comment: I have never heard of the thing you're proposing, but you could use a weaker system like a chromebook or netbook, and use x forwarding to access programs and files. It's obviously not quite the same, but it would have the added advantage of working remotely (over a decent internet connection, of course)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX gives details
You will need multiple graphics cards for the same
another link
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multiseat